# How can I cancel a blocked read/recvfrom system call on vxworks or linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, vxworks

In **TASK I**:

```
...

while (1)
{
  if (running == false)
  break;
  ret = read(fd, buf, size); /* Or: ret = recvfrom(sock, buf, size, 0, NULL, NULL); */
  ...
 }
```

In **task II**:

```
...
running = true;
/* ioctl(fd, FIOCANCEL, 0); */
close(fd);   /* Or: close(sock);*/
```

what should do in **task II** to cancel the blocked **task I**,

In **vxworks**, there is a function, `ioctl(fd, FIOCANCEL, 0)` to cancel a blocked read or write but it can not work. Probably because the driver can not support **"FIOCANCEL"**.

how to write task II in vxworks and linux? or are there any other way to do my task?

Comment: Receiving a signal will lead to read returning -1 and errno EINTR

Comment: mean task I "Receiving a signal"? The task I is blocking? how can it call receiving signal function?

Comment: Given that you use Linux und you know the process id of task 1, you can send a signal to it via calling kill(pid, SIGUSR1) in task 2. This will cause read to return with -1. Errno will be set to EINTR.

Comment: @ZhangBaolei Did you figure out how to cancel the blocked read task on VxWorks? I am encountering the same problem in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a read/recvfrom call is **impossible** on linux. You cannot write these tasks using the same API. On Linux you can use epoll and O_NONBLOCK to create the semantics of canceling a read/recvfrom.

It is **impossible** to do this using the same code for both linux and vxworks.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use blocking IO, this is a classic case of creating a thread with no (reachable) exit condition, which I consider to be a bug. The easiest example of how you should run your thread is as follows:

```
volatile bool _threadRunning = true;

void taskI()
{
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    while (_threadRunning == true)
    {
        ret = read(fd, buf, size);
        if (ret > 0)
        {
            // process buffer
        }
        else
        {
            // sleep for 1 millisecond or so...
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}


void taskII()
{
    _threadRunning = false;
    _taskI.join();
}
```