# Can I close a file descriptor in VxWorks without using FIOCANCEL?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, file-descriptor, vxworks

I am trying to find a proper way of closing/cancelling the file descriptor (`fd`) in VxWorks. As shown in the example, I have a task that does read operation forever, and I have a second task that will close the `fd`. In my system, `FIOCANCEL` is not supported, so I need to find an alternative way. So I am wondering if anyone have some ideas of how I can properly close the `fd` from the second task?

```
//Task 1
while (1)
{
  if (running == false)
  break;

  ret = read(fd, buf, size);
 }


// Task 2
running = false;
/* ioctl(fd, FIOCANCEL, 0); (not supported)*/
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is just a small programming error. The `close()` should work fine. You should just set the `running`-variable in task 2 to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the programming error. However, the running variable is actually not affecting the result outcome. I just added it in the example to make it more clear what the problem is (without the programming error ofc). The issue is that FIOCANCEL is not supported in my VxWorks system, and I am not entirely sure how to solve it.

Comment: Then you should consider using a nonblocking call, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781516/